# In push down automaton stack is shared with all other states?

Tags: pushdown-automaton

I want to know that in push down automaton stack is shared with all other states or not?

Comment: Maybe also/better suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pushdown-automata

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of push down automata, the states work with the stack; the concept of encapsulation or isolation is not part of the definition.

Naturally, since PDAs and other automata are constructed by us humans, you could potentially define an automaton where you had one stack per state. I doubt that it would be interesting.